# Backbone.Model.destroy throws "Uncaught Error: A “url” property or function must be specified"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm building a Backbone Application (with Marionette) and I have a deleteUser function like this:

```
//User is a Backbone.Model
UserController.prototype.deleteUser = function(user) {
    //Show jquery mobile loader
    $.mobile.loading( "show" );

    user.destroy({
        success: function(user) {
            console.log("Delete-Success: ", user);
            //Trigger an event that redirects to the List-Page
            App.channel.trigger("user:delete:success", user);
        },
        error: function(user) {
            console.log("Delete-Error: ", user);
            //Trigger an event that shows an error message and does not redirect
            App.channel.trigger("user:delete:error", user);
        }
    }).always(function(){
        $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
    });
};
```

This function works fine if the server is available and there is no error. It also shows the error message when the server is not reachable. The error message is displayed inline on top of the form, so that the user is able to try again later.

However, when I try to delete the model again after I got my error message for the first time, the console throws an error

> Uncaught Error: A “url” property or function must be specified.

My collection has an url attribute:

```
return Backbone.Collection.extend( {
    url: 'http://path-to-users'
});
```

And my model also has an urlRoot attribute

```
return Backbone.Model.extend( {
    urlRoot: 'http://path-to-users',
    defaults: {
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        age: ""
    }
```

Why does it throw the error message?

EDIT:

I call this function from my userApp.js:

```
var userApp = function() {
    this.Controller = new UserController();
    ...
    App.channel.on("user:delete", this.controller.deleteUser);
}
```

And App.channel.on is triggered by the "click #delete"-function of the EditUserView (a Marionette.ItemView):

```
deleteUser: function(){
    this.trigger("delete:clicked", this.model);
    return false;
}
```

The models do not get added to the collection. I simply fetch the collection from the server everytime I want to show it.
"channel" is defined as App.channel = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

Comment: can provide the code that calls `UserController` and how your model and collection interact (how models are added etc.)

Comment: Models are only added through model.save() and the collection is fetched fromthe server when needed. I provided a sample for calling UserController.

Comment: Do you ever tell your collection what Model to use?

Comment: No, I don't. Do you think that has something to do with the problem?

Comment: @ManuelHoffmann It's always nice to specify the model used for collection but in your case it shouldn't matter since your collection defines the URI.